# Syntax for SQL Grouping or subquery with reverse sorted dataset needing single string values not numeric summary?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Lets say I have a table that looks something like this:

ProjectSts:

```
ID   Proj  Status  LogDate    FundsRemain  LogBy
60   2     Quit    1/5/2013   Yes          QOVM
59   2     Quit    1/4/2013   Yes          YZYO
58   2     Quit    1/3/2013   No           XYZ
54   2     Start   1/1/2013   NA           QOVM
50   1     Quit    12/2/2012  Yes          UUOI
48   1     Quit    12/1/2012  Yes          OIJP
```

Currently what I am doing is a SQL statement to `SELECT * FROM  ProjSts WHERE Status = 'Quit' AND FundsRemain = 'Yes'`.  Then, within another application I am having the application manually read through all the resulting project status entries and select the chronologically first (earliest) such status for each project so it can be exported to a new table.

What I am wondering is how, if it's possible, to get this to happen all within the SQL statement.  I've looked at a lot of the tutorials on SQL Group By and they all show what to do if I wanted to sum, average, etc... a numeric field for all the entries for each project.  And I've looked at some tutorials on subqueries that show me how to generate an IN list, but I've not seen anything that would generate just a list of the post-sorted first record that meets certain criteria for each unique value within another field.

Ideally, from the example data above, the result would be:

```
ID   Proj  Status  LogDate    FundsRemain  LogBy
48   1     Quit    12/1/2012  Yes          OIJP
59   2     Quit    1/4/2013   Yes          YZYO
```

Sorry, I'm not the most advanced SQL user, but this would be great if I could get it to run within the SQL instead of having to rely on an external application to then go back and re-process the select results just to select what I actually need out of it.

Any help would be appreciated (PS: this is from a ctree database and I am currently using crystal reports 2008 for the initial data-extract)

Comment: What SQL engine are you using? SQL Server, Access, etc?

Comment: @PM77-1 I am currently using **Crystal Reports** to ODBC into a **CTree** database - database wasn't my choice and isn't able to be changed due to enterprise applications using it

Comment: Not familiar with `CTree`. Does it support standard SQL?

Comment: @PM77-1 so far I haven't found any SQL it hasn't supported or any requirement for non-standard syntax, but all I've been trying is more basic Select by statements primarily, so there could be some limitations on the extent to which it fully supports SQL

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to use any of the provided suggestions.  I liked the suggestions and I appreciate the help and information about various SQL techniques, but once I had attempted them, I realized that, while probably 99% of the time it is how I presented in the example data, there are a few cases where the LogDates are not each unique within a project so there were still a few cases where there were duplicate records returned for one project.  As a matter of fact, it is only the combination of LogDate and LogBy that would make them unique within my real data.

Comment: I was able to use these concepts afterall, I just had to do some manipulating and combining of the couple of proposed answers to make it work with the specifics of the actual dataset and work within the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version with `correlated sub-query` (using `MySQL` syntax):

```
SELECT ct.*
FROM ctree ct
WHERE ct.logDate = (SELECT MIN(logDate) FROM ctree ct2 
                    WHERE ct.proj = ct2.proj AND 
                          status='Quit' AND 
                          fundsRemain='Yes') 
ORDER BY id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58f99/6)

**RESULT** (based on your data):

```
ID  PROJ    STATUS  LOGDATE                        FUNDSREMAIN  LOGBY
48     1    Quit    December, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 Yes         OIJP
59     2    Quit    January, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000  Yes         YZYO
```

Comment: I was able to use this concept but had to adjust to make it work with the actual data.  I used a built in function in ctree called rowid (I found the documentation) that returns a unique row number for each record and use the min property basically as you show to get the needed records out of the database.

Side affect: by running this instead of Select * from table where field = abc, SQL request takes noteably longer, but reduction in numb records returned and reduction from 3 steps to 1 reduced total response time from 10-15 min to about 60 sec. Plus process runs more automated this way.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your RDBMS, one option is joining the table to itself using the `MIN` aggregate:

```
select p.*
from ProjSts p
  inner join (
    select min(LogDate) minLogDate, Proj
    from ProjSts
    where status='Quit' and FundsRemain = 'Yes'
    group by Proj
    ) p2 on p.Proj = p2.Proj and p.LogDate = p2.minLogDate
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45097/1)

While I'm not sure about `CTree`, if your database supports `Row_Number`, this is perhaps an easier solution:

```
select *
from (
  select *, 
    Row_Number() Over (Partition By Proj Order By LogDate) rn
  from ProjSts
  where status='Quit' and FundsRemain = 'Yes'
    ) p
where rn = 1
```

- [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45097/3)

Comment: The row_number idea was useful though not supported exactly the same way in ctree.  I found the documentation and it has a rowid function that returns the row internal identifier that appears to prob be immutable for the record (not set within the query).  Didn't use your idea per-say, but it got me looking for the right key words and led me to the function I needed.  (Also, yes I'm newer to this, but, I hadn't used sql fiddle myself before, so exposure to that resource in relevant setting was useful)